# Local vs Live - Multithreading using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor

Tags: spring, multithreading, tomcat, job-scheduling

I have a Java-Configuration with this annotaions:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("XXX")
public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
      ...
  @Override
  public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("Rm-");
    executor.setConcurrencyLimit(50);
    executor.setThreadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    return executor;
  }
}
```

Then I have 3 Schedulers

```
/**
 * Schedul on application start.
 */
@Transactional
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = Long.MAX_VALUE, initialDelay = 200)
public void initialReplicate() {
    replicateFromTime(0l);
}


/**
 * Every minute check for synchronization.
 */
@Transactional
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * * ")
public void replicate() {
    long minutesSinceTimeRecord = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 / 60;
    replicateFromTime(minutesSinceTimeRecord);
}

@Transactional
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void build() {
   LOG.info("Check if somethings to build.");
}
```

What the replicate-from-time does:

It calculates if the day is over, if so, it replicate once per day (and once at appstart) the schema of a database.
For every table in the database one connection is created.

```
@Async
@Transactional
public Future<Void> readTable(TableModel table, String jdbcurl, Driver driver, Properties props, String schema,
        Set<Throwable> errors, String catalogName) {
    Connection connect = connectionService.connect(jdbcurl, errors, driver, props);

    final DatabaseMetaData metadata;
    try {
        metadata = connect.getMetaData();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        errors.add(e);
        try {
            connect.close();
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            errors.add(e2);
        }
        return new AsyncResult<Void>(null);
    }
    ...
```

There are 804 tables of any kind in the database (views, tables, temporary-tables, ...). For every table one connection is created. Makes 804 threads.

The database is on the machin as the app. I test from localhost.

### Problem:

On the remote-server, on appstart it replicates successfully. But no other scheduler are executed anymore except the `public void build()`-Scheduler. But only 48 times (see the limit of 50 threads in the configuration).

From local-server, on appstart it replicates successfully. All 3 schedulers are working as expected.

The tomcat on the server should run all schedulers, but it runs only one. The tomcat on my local machine run all schedulers.

### Confusion

I expected to have more problems in a local environment, connected to a remote server than inside the remote-server itself.

### Question

Any idea why the remote server have problems but my local machine not?

### Technical details

- Local is a `apache-tomcat-8.5.27`.
- Remote is a `apache-tomcat-8.5.15`.
- Database to replicate schema is a postgres.